# How to finding what object groups an ip address belongs to in a Cisco ASA

Tags: python

I have a task to determine the use of IP's in a object group on a Cisco ASA. I am coding in python. The config has the following

```
object-group network VIPUSERS
description VIPUSER Addresses
network-object host 192.168.0.10
network-object host 192.168.0.11
!
object-group network USERS
description USER Addresses
network-object host 192.168.0.10
network-object host 192.168.0.11
network-object host 192.168.0.12
network-object host 192.168.0.13
network-object host 192.168.0.14
network-object host 192.168.0.15
!
object-group network SERVERS
description SERVER addresses
network-object host 192.168.100.10
network-object host 192.168.100.11
network-object host 192.168.100.12
network-object host 192.168.100.13
network-object host 192.168.100.14
network-object host 192.168.100.15
!
object-group service USER-SERVER-PORTS
service-object icmp echo
service-object icmp echo-reply
service-object tcp eq 21
service-object tcp eq 25
service-object tcp eq 80
service-object tcp eq 443
```

The script takes the input 192.168.0.11. The output should be

```
object-group network VIPUSERS
object-group network USERS
```

I can search the said input, however unable to backtrack and get the group to which it belongs. I have so far only come up with a logic to keep a variable with the value "object-group network" and parse the next lines until we get the the desired input value. Once found, print the variable.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the easiest way to accomplish this ?

Make the computer do it. Regular expression to describe each section starting with `object-group` and ending with `!`. (NB. I put a ! at the end of your text to make all the sections fit the same pattern).

Capture the last word on the 'object-group' line, and all the following lines until the !

Then check if the content lines have the IP, if so, print the group name.

```
s = '''
object-group network VIPUSERS
description VIPUSER Addresses
network-object host 192.168.0.10
network-object host 192.168.0.11
!
object-group network USERS
description USER Addresses
network-object host 192.168.0.10
network-object host 192.168.0.11
network-object host 192.168.0.12
network-object host 192.168.0.13
network-object host 192.168.0.14
network-object host 192.168.0.15
!
object-group network SERVERS
description SERVER addresses
network-object host 192.168.100.10
network-object host 192.168.100.11
network-object host 192.168.100.12
network-object host 192.168.100.13
network-object host 192.168.100.14
network-object host 192.168.100.15
!
'''

import re

for m in re.finditer(r'object-group \w+ (\w+)\r?\n([^!]+)!?', s):
  group, content = m.groups()
  if '192.168.0.10' in content:
    print(group)
```